# Determine default value for a product option via BigCommerce v2 API

Tags: bigcommerce

In the BigCommerce Admin UI, you can establish the "default" value for an option via the "Make Default" checkbox in the "Configure Multiple Choice" list when editing an option.

Is there any way to get determine which option value is default via the v2 API? I've searched the API documentation and XML results, and it doesn't seem to be anywhere. I'm hoping I'm missing it.

Comment: I don't think that is available at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news everyone! `is_default` attribute has been added. You can check the docs here:

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/objects/v2/option_value
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/options/values

Comment: What about setting the default value for a "multi-line text" type option. Is this possible?

Comment: Default value is not supported on the API for things like "multi-line text", "date", or plain "text field" options.  Basically options where the value is not a fixed list of choices.  The default is available for all fixed list options like Select, Color Swatch, and Product List.  The other option type should become fully supported in the future.

Answer (score 0):

After 6 weeks I got a reply from BigCommerce confirming that there is no way to get this information form the API:

> My apologies for the delay in a response on this issue. Unfortunately
>   at this time the "Default" value is not a property for an option
>   selection in the API. The default selection is made in the control
>   panel when editing the option itself and then the option values on
>   Step 2 of that screen, but as you'll see in our documentation here the
>   "Default" property is not accessible via API at current.

Comment: Do we know if they were planning to update this? It's almost a year later now and I just stumbled across the same problem. There is no way to get the default value or any of the other additional information for the option via the API. For example, for an option of type "Date field", there is no way to retrieve the default value or the maximum allowed value via the API. I'm trying to figure out a way to keep products from one store in sync with another store. Not having this data available through the API makes it nearly impossible.

Comment: I gave up on them ages ago. Slow support, lousy apis, poor reliability. Glad I'm done with that client.